# How secure is connecting the monero wallet via SSH tunneling to a self run remote server?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, remote-access, monerod

Since running the monero daemon to sync with the blockchain requires substantial bandwidth and uptime, I have recently switched to connecting my wallet (with the local wallet files) to a remote instance on my own publicly available server (without the wallet files). I am using a SSH tunnel (-L 18081:localhost:18081) to map my local port to the servers port - now my only concern is the security of this approach. Is there any way to intercept the communication between wallet and daemon - or even worse the password etc?

Answer (score 5):

The wallet password is never transmitted. Tunneling through ssh should be safe, assuming you have a good ssh key.